# cmd escaped after SoapUI test is finished

Tags: cmd, soapui, test-runner

I am calling SaopUI testrunnet from cmd file.

The problem is that lines after command for testrunner are not executed

I have unchecked "Fail testcase on error" checkbox in soap ui without any help.
Anyway, i have this issue regardless of test was successful or not

this is my command

```
%SoapUIPath%\testrunner.bat-sTestSuite %projectPath% -I -r -P var2=%var2% -P var1=%var1%
echo ###Test finished###
```

Echo "Test finished" will not be executed

Comment: `call "%SoapUIPath%\testrunner.bat"  ...`. Without the `call`, execution flow is not returned to the caller.

Comment: thanks, add it as answer please so i could mark it. thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one batch file directly invokes another one, the execution flow is transfered to the called file, and not returned to the caller.

To retrieve the execution flow after the called file has ended, we need to use the `call` command

```dos
call "%SoapUIPath%\testrunner.bat" ....
```